# mysql regexp query hangs, but displays results when mysql process restarts

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, left-join

I have two tables. Table1 is 10mil rows, Table2 is 1mil rows. I need to search Table2 with regexp and then join the tables.

When I do:

```
SELECT * FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 
ON table1.ID1=table2.ID2 
WHERE table2.column REGEX 'regexp'
```

the query never finishes.

However, when I kill mysqld process, it displays the results (in PHPMyAdmin) and the execution time displayed is just 0.07 sec.

If I use LIKE instead of REGEXP, there is no problem, neither is there problem if I use REGEX on table2 alone.

ID1 & ID2 are indexed. If I EXPLAIN the select, it shows the keys are used.

Any idea, what's wrong?

Comment: If you have a complex regex over 1 millions rows that can take a while.

Comment: You cannot do a regex on a table name; do it on a column name (e.g. `WHERE table2.someColumn REGEX 'regexp'`)

Comment: I don't think that `regexp` uses an index, even for a constant string.  Use `like` instead.

Comment: Do a 'desc' to see if the query is using any indexing. I think that @SverriM.Olsen is right though - the query looks kind of fishy.

Comment: @juergend that is not the problem, as I say, the regex on table2 alone works fine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes, I know that, I index the IDs. I know regexp takes time, but again, on table2 alone it runs ok. I can't use like in this case.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: sorry, forgot to add the column name!

Comment: @ethrbunny: as I said, I did that, it uses the indexes of the IDs. The column also has a unique index and a fulltext index, but that's not the problem.

Comment: A correction to my previous comment: I do not know whether it is *possible* to do a `REGEX` on a table name, but it sure seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: again sorry, my bad, that's not what I wanted to do, typo in my question, not in my actual query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the whole problem was that the ID fields in the two tables were of a different type (mediumint vs. int). Once I changed them both to int, the queries are fast.
Since the engine is MyISAM, I could not use the foreign keys that would probably make me aware of the problem much sooner.